# Minipage and multicols, vertical alignment

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage, multicol

I want to create two columns next to each other. The left side contains a text in two columns using the *multicol* package. On the left side is some other content.

I've tried *minipage*, but in combination with *multicol* it fails in vertical aligning both minipages correctly.
Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
   \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        \noindent
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \blindtext
        \end{multicols}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
            \blindtext
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

The result, with a vertical misalignment of the top of both texts:
[image: misaligned minipages]

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to SE! I do not what is cause of your problem but this (dirty trick) can help: `....\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
~
\vspace{-2\baselineskip}
\begin{multicols}{1}
...`

Comment: Also, you should use {\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth - 0.5\columnsep} for the column width.

Comment: You have explanation in @egreg answer :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set an anchor at the top for `[t]` to take effect, because the top line inside the `multicols` environment is *not* the top line in the enveloping `minipage`: `\vspace{0pt}` is sufficient. Also you need to countermand the insertion of a glob of glue (we need to back up by the difference between `\topskip` and the height of a strut) and to set an initial `\strut` to ensure good alignment between the baselines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol,calc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\noindent % or the indent would apply
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth-0.5em} % some separation
  \vspace{0pt} % anchor for [t]
  \vspace{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\topskip}% remove excess glue
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \strut\makebox[0pt][l]{\vrule width 10cm height 0pt depth 0.1pt}%
    \blindtext
  \end{multicols}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth-0.5em} % some separation
  \vspace{0pt} % anchor for [t]
  \strut\blindtext
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The rule shows the alignment. Thanks to Frank Mittelbach for spotting a mistake.

Comment: might be mistaken Enrico, but this still looks misaligned

Comment: Yes, the real backup depends on `\splittopskip`, rather than `\lineskip`.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't using paracol and multicol be an easier approach?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
   \begin{paracol}{2}
       \begin{multicols}{2}
            \blindtext
        \end{multicols}
  \switchcolumn
     \blindtext
  \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: paracol seems to target specifically bilingual texts and is therefore restricted to two columns

Comment: No, it supports multiple columns, and can even specify columns with different widths.  The question is whether you want to align columns or flow between them.

Comment: Okay, so it is definitely an option. Thank you!